# Maven test classes custom directory layout

Tags: java, maven

**Tools :**

Apache Maven 3

**Issue :**

I am working on one legacy project for which Junit test classes are not following standard maven directory structure `(src/test/java)`

They follow below structure.

```
src 
  -- org 
        --example 
              -- Java classes here
```

Query :

Is there any way to tell maven to pick up test classes from this location instead of  `- src/test/java ?`

`mvn clean install` is not picking test classes right now because of this custom structure

Comment: What is stopping you from moving the source files? It really is the best solution.

Comment: Yes . I agree. I want to do this. But sheer volume of files made me think the other way round

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look here:

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3//maven-model/maven.html#class_build

In your `<build>` section there is a section `<testSourceDirectory>` which can be used to specify folder/folders with tests.